# Clicking a 'homepage' link in robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am writing test scripts using the Robot Framework & Selenium2Library for testing a web application.

The problem I have right now is that after the user has logged in, my script does not click the 'homepage' link to proceed to the Homepage, the application just disappears and command prompt gives me 'passed' results.

I want the script to click the link and then proceed to the Homepage,This is my code:

```
ClickHomePage
Click Link   xpath=//*[@href="itinerary.php"]
```

I would appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Check if you are invoking `quit()` too early right after _click the 'homepage' link_?

Comment: I don't see any statements after the click link, so the test goes to the home page and then exits. What do you want it to do after it has proceeded to the home page? Have you tried adding `capture page screenshot` or some verification steps after clicking the link?

Comment: Have you tried adding a simple `Sleep    10s` statement after the click. It's likely clicked and then quite right afterwards. Which is expected behaviour.

Comment: @BryanOakley , yes I do, I have this statement after    click link :

Comment: Launch Homepage    Go To  ${To_Homepage}

Comment: How do you know that it's not simply doing those statements and then exiting really fast?

Comment: @A.Kootstra thank you, it's working. I am able to proceed to the Homepage

Comment: @BryanOakley I must say that I am still new to the robot framework and selenium. I was confused as to why the application was exiting fast when I wanted it to proceed to Homepage

Answer (score 2):

I have seen things like this generally when running tests on selenium. They could be really fast. I sometimes have to use breakpoints and debugging if I really want to see things happening during the test.

Unless you have another line of code after clicking the link, that is where the execution will end. Therefore, if you do want to see the homepage you may need to include a line a code that interacts with the homepage or simply a wait statement after clicking the link.

Comment: there was no line of code after clicking the link,  I had to add another statement in order for me to see the application proceeding to the Homepage,    Sleep 10s worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code another way.

```
 *** Variable ***
     ${profile}          https://web.facebook.com/xxx
 *** Keywords ***
     Click Profile
     [Arguments]        ${xpath}
     Click Element      ${xpath}
 *** Test Cases ***
     Go To           ${profile}
```

Hope to help.